# I get the error undefined reference to `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1'. How do I fix it?

Tags: c, gcc, openssl

I get this error when I try to compile the below code. I installed openssl libraries. I don't know programming. The error is:
"ccS3fmrV.o:wa_pbkdf2.c:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Can someone help? Thanks.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 unsigned char pass[1024];      // passphrase read from stdin
 unsigned char salt[1024];      // salt 
 int salt_len;                  // salt length
 int ic;                        // iteration
 unsigned char result[1024];    // result
 FILE *fp_salt;

 if ( argc != 3 ) {
  fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s salt_file iteration < passwd_file > binary_key_file \n", argv[0]);
  exit(1);
 }

 ic = atoi(argv[2]);
  
 fp_salt = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 if(!fp_salt) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error opening salt file: %s\n", argv[1]);
  exit(2);
 }

 salt_len=0;
 int ch; 
 while((ch = fgetc(fp_salt)) != EOF) {  
  salt[salt_len++] = (unsigned char)ch;  
 } 

    fclose(fp_salt); 
   
    fgets(pass, 1024, stdin);
    if ( pass[strlen(pass)-1] == '\n' )
  pass[strlen(pass)-1] = '\0';
  
 PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pass, strlen(pass), salt, salt_len, ic, 16, result);

 fwrite(result, 1, 16, stdout);

 return(0);
}
```

Comment: What command line did you use to compile this program?  You probably need a `-l` flag to link the appropriate library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used: gcc -o wa_pbkdf2 wa_pbkdf2.c -lssl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I get the error undefined reference to `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1'. How do I fix it?

`PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1` was added in 1.0.0 (IIRC). So be sure you are using OpenSSL 1.0.0 or higher. There's an OpenSSL man page on [PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.html), but it has an empty history.

If you are using OpenSSL 1.0.1, then be sure you are including `libcrypto` for the linker. Your compile/link command should look something like:

```
gcc wa_pbkdf2.c -o wa_pbkdf2.exe -lcrypto
```