# gcc not compiling with openssl includes

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, openssl, mingw

I'm having some trouble trying to compile some code that includes openssl using the following gcc command

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -std=c89 -pedantic -static -isystemC:\Users\username\Downloads\openssl-1.1.1-win64-mingw\openssl-1.1.1-win64-mingw\include -LC:\Users\username\Downloads\openssl-1.1.1-win64-mingw\openssl-1.1.1-win64-mingw\lib -o "roulette.exe" "c:\Users\username\Documents\Progetti_Info\roulette\roulette.c" -lcrypto -lssl
```

I'm getting this errors here that after a week of searching I can't really figure out how to fix

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPlU9Zl.o:roulette.c:(.text+0x23d): undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPlU9Zl.o:roulette.c:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1'
```

Here is a snippet of code if you need to take a look

```
#include "openssl/evp.h"
#include "openssl/sha.h"
#include "openssl/rand.h"


    char *input = "test";
    int length = 4;

    int ITERATION = 512000;

    int SHA1_LEN = 20;
    unsigned char* out = (unsigned char*)calloc(SHA1_LEN, sizeof(unsigned char));

    int SALT_LEN = 5;
    unsigned char* salt = (unsigned char*)calloc(SALT_LEN, sizeof(unsigned char));
    RAND_bytes(salt, SALT_LEN);

    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(input, strlen(input), salt, SALT_LEN, ITERATION, SHA1_LEN, out);
    printf("%s", out);
```

thanks to anyone that will try to help me solve this

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538343/i-get-the-error-undefined-reference-to-pkcs5-pbkdf2-hmac-sha1-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I already checked my version of openssl and I have downloaded 1.1.1 precompiled binaries and libraries

Comment: From the command line - you have your own openssl. Do you use dynamic libraries, or static libraries  (in C:\Users\username\Downloads\openssl-1.1.1-win64-mingw\openssl-1.1.1-win64-mingw\lib) ?

Comment: I think i have both static and dynamic because I have both .a and .dll files

EDIT: the .dll files have another .a extension added to them

Comment: Having '.dll.a' suffix is not common practice. On surface, the '.dll.a' will not be used. It is possible that the '.a' are broken ? same error message occur when you omit the crypto library from the linking

Comment: removing -l from the compiling command it gives the same error, yes

Comment: Long Shot: Try to reference the 'dll.a' files directly (full path), instead of using the -l.

Comment: I tried it and it still gives me the same error... tomorrow I will be at my university were I can install Perl and I will try to compile myself the openssl binaries, hoping that will fix it

Comment: Based on the source code shown above, you only need `-lcrypto`. You do not need `-lssl` because you are not using SSL/TLS functions.